# can't get .on() to work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this topic has been asked a lot before but I read a lot of stackoverflow posts and can't figure it out. Either I'm doing a silly mistake or using the code wrong. In any case I'd appreciate other sets of eyes.

My code is actually simple. Elements are being dragged into boxes and I want the user to be able to close the dragged boxes so they can redo the dragging.

```
  <div id="questionContainer">

  <div class='row-fluid'>
      <div class='span3 box-content'>
        <div class="box span12">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Column 1" />
        </div>
        <div class="box span12  groupBoxes">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class='span3 box-content'>
        <div class="box span12">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Column 2" />
        </div>
        <div class="box span12  groupBoxes">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class='span3 box-content'>
        <div class="box span12">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Column 3" />
        </div>
        <div class="box span12  groupBoxes">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class='span3 box-content'>
        <div class="box span12">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Column 4" />
        </div>
        <div class="box span12 groupBoxes">
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Then there is the javascript which appends the dragged element. And I have an .on() function there that doesn't work at all.

```
    $( ".groupBoxes" ).droppable({
      accept: ".sDrag",
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        var studentID = $(ui.draggable).attr('Uid'); 
        var studentName = $(ui.draggable).find(".sName").text();
        console.log(studentID + ' ' + studentName); 

         var dropbox = "<div class='box questionBox' Uid='"+studentID+"' ><div class='box-content box-statistic'><h3 class='title text-error'>"+studentName+"</h3><div class='icon-remove align-right card-remove' style='font-size:12px'></div></div> </div>";

          $(this).append(dropbox);


      }
    });

$("#questionContainer").on('click', '.card-remove',  function () {
    console.log('hi');
    var student = $(this).parent('.questionBox').attr('Uid'); // get user number
    var box = $(".studentBox[value='"+student+"']")// find the original object through user
    box.removeClass('muted-background').addClass('sDrag');// back in the original object, add class sDrag and remove class muted-background
    // remove the object clicked

});
```

Any ideas about what's going wrong here?

Comment: Can you create an example at jsFiddle.net?

Comment: A jsfiddle would be useful to debug it for you, but at a guess i'd say make sure the .on() binder is inside a document.ready callback (so you know the element exists before javascript tries to look it up for binding). If that doesn't work, it may be that droppable is overwriting the click event, in which case you might have to do something funky with the ondrop event and working out if it has been moved or not.

Comment: @user1 I don't think, you can even put `$(document).on()` as your parent

Comment: Just to be sure, does your first function work correctly?

Comment: Just a suggestion, but maybe the element which you are creating is actually hidden below the Dragged element. e.g. The dragged element now has a -n top margin, which is overlapping the newly added element.

Comment: Maybe you have copied wrong, but you missed a closing `</div>` and a `;` or `,` at the end of `var box` line

Comment: Thanks for all the comments! The first function works, in that the dropping happens. I tried it with $(document), and this is wrapped around code that loads when the page loads. I'll make a jsfiddle now to give you guys a better idea.

Comment: @Caner I hacked up [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U2r3s/4/) with what you provided above and clicks events are occurring as expected.  There must be some other interaction (styles, code, other) that is causing this not to work for you.

Comment: Here's the fiddle I worked up: http://jsfiddle.net/eanPb/ but it's not working for me. This also doesn't have any other code dependencies I'm using.

Comment: RESOLVED: Tim B James, you were exactly right. Taking z-index out resolved it. Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 0):

try to define dropbox outside the function

```
var dropbox;
    $( ".groupBoxes" ).droppable({
  accept: ".sDrag",
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    var studentID = $(ui.draggable).attr('Uid'); 
    var studentName = $(ui.draggable).find(".sName").text();
    console.log(studentID + ' ' + studentName); 

      dropbox = "<div class='box questionBox' Uid='"+studentID+"' ><div class='box-content box-statistic'><h3 class='title text-error'>"+studentName+"</h3><div class='icon-remove align-right card-remove' style='font-size:12px'></div></div> </div>";

      $(this).append(dropbox);


  }
});

$("#questionContainer").on('click', '.card-remove',  function () {
    console.log('hi');
    var student = $(this).parent('.questionBox').attr('Uid'); // get user number
    var box = $(".studentBox[value='"+student+"']")// find the original object through user
    box.removeClass('muted-background').addClass('sDrag');// back in the original object, add class sDrag and remove class muted-background
    // remove the object clicked

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried this, but it's not making any difference.